# How to solve 'Column' object is not callable in Pandas Databricks?

Tags: pandas, databricks

I am trying to build histogram using this code:

```
    import sys
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')

    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

     df3 = (spark.read
     .format("csv")
     .option("header", "true")
     .option("inferSchema", "true")
     .load("/databricks-datasets/samples/population-vs-price/data_geo.csv")
      )

      df3['2015 median sales price'].hist()
      plt.show()
```

But it gives me error 'Column' object is not callable.
I tried df3.select("2015 median sales price").show() and it works for showing the data.
Can someone help me please to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi. In the spirit of [ask], how about an [mre] ? spark, df3?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `.hist()` on a column this way. Do the following instead

```py
df.toPandas().hist(column=['2015 median sales price'])
```

Comment: I tried this thank you, but got 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'hist' error (((

Comment: You have to transform your spark DataFrame into a pandas DataFrame to use the hist() method. Se updated answer.